# On what is the Directness badge based in Anomaly Warzone Earth?

Tags: achievements, anomaly-warzone-earth

I've just finished level 3 in Anomaly Warzone Earth using the (by my knowledge) shortest path available. Unfortunately I still didn't get a golden Directness badge, but only silver.

Is there any other measure which is taken into account in order to win the golden badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directness is purely time or distance based (they're the same). Double check anywhere where you have to back track and pay close attention to the junction timers.

**Edit:** This is a junction timer.  Now that I have a screen shot, I should have called them ETA timers.  They appear when you float the mouse over a junction.  Try a few routes and see if you can minimize this number.

[image: Juntion Timer]

Here's the most direct route through mission 3.  Good luck staying alive!

[image: East, East, East, North, East, East]
[image: North, North, West, West]
[image: West, West, North, North, South, South]
[image: East, South, South, West, West]

Comment: The junction timers?

Comment: Thanks for the great update! Staying alive shouldn't be too difficult, as you actually seem to be able to play on casual to win the badges. :) You don't have separate badges per difficulty.

Comment: Bah!  Where's the fun in that.  ;-)  Wait until you go for Gold Directness on Mission 12.  That one's intense!  :-D

Comment: Humm, something is wrong... I've set *exactly* this route, have the same partials and total time, and still getting silver medal. Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: @MestreLion, that's very odd.  I wonder if it's being picky?  What if you adjust the routes in the second picture so that it's the same distance but with less corners?